# How to call child class function from parent class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm new to C++ language and I'm doing library Management System.
i have a classes like this.
eg:

```
class mainLibrary{
  void library(){
  cout<<"Welcome to Our Library. Please choose following options"<<endl;
  cout<<"1. Member Section, 2. Lending Section"<<endl;
  if(userinput==1){
   memberclassfunction();//Error : use of undeclared identifier 'memberclassfunction'.
  }else{
  lendingclassfunction();//Error : use of undeclared identifier 'lendingclassfunction'.
 }
}
};

class Member:public mainLibrary{
 void memberclassfunction(){
 //do something
 }
};

class lending:public Member{
 void lendingclassfunction(){
 //do something
}
};

class mainSystem:public lending{
 //this is empty and inherit all. 
};
void main{
 mainSystem s1;
 s1.library();
}
```

i did something like this. but in mainLibrary Class if i call memberclassfunction(); program show me error. use of undeclared identifier 'memberclassfunction'.

can anyone help me how to do that. i think i have to do something with pointers right?

Comment: Not about your question, but... you are using class hierarchies for aggregation, and that is usually a bad idea. Just create a different class for each of your program concepts, and then do the `mainSystem` have a member variable of the ones it needs. You'll notice that your code will be easier to write and use.

Answer (score 0):

memberclassfunction must be a virtual function in the mainLibrary, meaning that the mainLibrary will become an interface and you will not be able to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `memberclassfunction` nor `lendingclassfunction` are members of class `mainLibrary`, that's why the compiler is giving you these errors. I think your intention was to make these functions [`virtual`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Whenever class `B` inherit from class `A`, the former gets the latter's members, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not a good idea to have a base class depend on methods in its sub-classes. However if you MUST do this, you could always cast `this` to the subclass and if the cast succeeds then you can call the method.

```
lending *lendingThis = dynamic_cast<lending *>(this);
if (lendingThis) {
    lendingThis->lendingclassfunction();
}
```